# Python, append curl results to list with urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am trying to append the results from a curl request using urllib3 to a list. You can see from my below attempt that I am out of my depth already :)

```
import urllib3
import json
import csv

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'URL')
mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
{'origin': '127.0.0.1'}
datas = list()
for mail in mails:
    datas.append(mail)
```

I fixed the syntax errors thanks for the answers. The results however appear to be incorrect.

What I expect one entry in the list to look like:

```
{"success":true,"data:[{"id":20758,"company_id":117376,"user_id":1529193,"done":false,"type":"email","reference_type":"none","reference_id":null,"due_date":"2017-09-01","due_time":"","duration":"","add_time":"2017-01-13
```

What I get is ONLY this, nothing else:

```
success 
data
additional_data 
related_object
```

I am guessing it is something to do with the JSON hierarchy?

Comment: Don't you mean `datas.append(mail)` ? You also miss a `:` after your for. Please provide more information about the error you get.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Ok so, obvious mistakes fixed thanks Arnaud. That cleared up the syntax errror. Feel kinda stupid now. But, the response is still wrong. The output i expect is like this.
{"success":true,"data":
[{"id":20758,"company_id":117376,"user_id":1529193,"done":false,"type":"email","reference_type":"none","reference_id":null,"due_date":"2017-09-01","due_time":"","duration":"","add_time":"2017-01-13 

and the result i actually get is
success
data
additional_data
related_objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over the result from mails. mails is a json output.
To add the result to a list just do.

```
datas = list()
mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
datas.append(mails)
```

**Output:**

```
[{"success":true,"data:[{"id":20758,"company_id":117376,"user_id":1529193......]
```

List of json.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few typos :

- Your `for` misses a `:`. It should be `for mail in mails:`
- You want to append `mail` not `mails` i.e. `datas.append(mail)`

Does that solve your syntax errors ?

Comment: Ok so, obvious mistakes fixed thanks Arnaud. That cleared up the syntax errror. Feel kinda stupid now. But, the response is still wrong. The output i expect is like this. {"success":true,"data": [{"id":20758,"company_id":117376,"user_id":1529193,"done":false,"type":"email","reference_type":"none","reference_id":null,"due_date":"2017-09-01","due_time":"","duration":"","add_time":"2017-01-13 and the result i actually get is success data additional_data related_objects

Comment: Please update your / create new question with proper formatting and clear expectations. It is unclear what your results are.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo while using `append`, also some syntax error:

1.the line `{'origin': '127.0.0.1'}` should be set to a variable or to be commented.

2. a `for` loop requires a colon `:` at the end of line in order to start the for loop scope.

the code should be like:

```
import urllib3
import json
import csv

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'URL')
mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
# {'origin': '127.0.0.1'}

datas = list()
for mail in mails:
    datas.append(mail)
```